# How to send request to DialogFlow agent from custom chat UI?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a use case where I need more richer chat messages with complex GUI messages which are not supported in the existing Dialogflow integrations list. So I am planning to create my own chat window and UI.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find any Dialogflow docs which explains how can I submit user utterances to Dialogflow and get the response back so that I can update my custom chat UI.

How can I submit user utterances from custom Chat UI to Dialogflow and get the response back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis), which lets you send messages to Dialogflow for it to turn into an Intent, possibly send it to a fulfillment server, and then send all this back to your client.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. I'm sorry, I have just started learning dialogflow and was not able to find this doc.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for! Documentation isn't always easy to navigate, and now we have a question on SO that may help point the way for others.